# App stops working after adding Autofac Webapi2. No exceptions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, autofac

We are in the process of adding Dependency Injection into our application using Autofac. It's been going well until we added the Autofac.Webapi2 v4.3.1 package. Our web app includes both standard MVC controllers and Web API controllers so we include both Autofac.Mvc5 & Autofac.WebApi2 packages.

When we run the app we get no exceptions, can't hit a breakpoint and don't see any errors in Event Viewer.

The browser just displays with a generic message:

> We are sorry. We are not able to service your request.

I've updated the code to setup and register the Web API controllers and Filters, but we see the issue with and without the code changes.

I'm assuming there's an incompatibility with one of new new references. How can I find the issue without build errors or exceptions?

Comment: this error your custome message error?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. Mahdi Anjam's question led me to an application we have that intercepts requests with shortlinks and redirects to the correct URL (i.e. https://myapp/54sl3). It displays a basic error.html instead of details. Once I turned the custom errors off I got the full error response.

The issue ended up being the autofac.Webapi2 package added a handler to our Web.Config, but the handler was already created (handler name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"). This caused a duplicate key in the list of handlers. No exceptions in our code, or IIS or the Event Viewer. I just needed to turn off our Custom error page.